# Result of query with Multiple ORs is not in order of ORs

Tags: mysql

I'm pulling a list of ids based on a pool of names that were pulled from an OCR scan.  The list results fine, but not in the order of the multiple ORs.
...mysql

```
SELECT sid FROM students WHERE name ='Leah' OR name = 'Sowaka'
```

...
(truncated for brevity.)
the results are 44 and 9, even though 'leah' is '9'.
Any easy solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the results sorted as they would be by the name:

```
SELECT sid FROM students WHERE name ='Leah' OR name = 'Sowaka' order by name
```

If you want them sorted as they appear in the `OR`s:

```
SELECT sid FROM students WHERE name ='Leah' OR name = 'Sowaka' 
  order by 
    case name 
      when 'Leah' then 1
      when 'Sowaka' then 2
      .....................
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to create a derived table with `UNION ALL`s, that contains the names and an ordinal. Then inner join that table and sort by the ordinal.

```
SELECT s.sid
       FROM students s
            INNER JOIN (SELECT 1 ordinal,
                               'Leah' name
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT 2 ordinal,
                               'Sowoka' name
                        ...) x
                        ON x.name = s.name
       ORDER BY x.ordinal;
```